# Unable to get the correct SVM gradient using vectorization

Tags: svm, gradient-descent, loss-function, gradient

I was attempting the CS231n Assignment 1 for vectorizing the computation of the SVM gradients. dW is the gradient matrix. The following is my attempt:

```
def svm_loss_vectorized(W, X, y, reg):

  num_train = X.shape[0]
  loss = 0.0
  dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

  scores = X.dot(W)
  margins = np.maximum(0, scores - scores[y] + 1)
  margins[y] = 0

  # indices gets the position in the margins matrix where entry is > 0
  indices = np.argwhere(margins > 0)
  i = indices[:, 0]
  j = indices[:, 1]

  dW[:, j] += np.transpose(X[i])
  dW[:, y[i]] -= np.transpose(X[i])
  loss = np.sum(margins)

  # average it
  loss /= num_train
  dW /= num_train

  # regularization
  loss += reg * np.sum(W * W)
  dW += reg * W

  return loss, dW
```

My loss calculation is correct, however, the gradient calculated is off by a huge margin. Could someone please help me understand what I'm missing here?